# Lazy logging evaluation in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, lazy-evaluation

Is there a way to do lazy evaluation when logging?

For instance `console.log("Result: ", throwingFunc())` won't log the first argument (`"Result: "`), as the 2nd argument, `throwingFunc()`, will get evaluated before the call to `console.log(..)`.

I also tried `logger.debug("Result: ", () => throwingFunc())` with `log4js` and other libraries, but to my surprise none of them worked...

Comment: Questions seeking library recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow, as they often lead to subjective answers. Have you explored any code patterns or methods within log4js (or similar libraries) to achieve your desired functionality?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's not library recommendation request. it's a question how to achieve lazy evaluation in whatever logging library, or even `console.log`. Neither Google nor ChatGPT yielded any insight. I improved the question to be clearer about it.

Comment: The reason I think you're looking for a library is due to _"Is there a logging library that does lazy evaluation?"_. Thank you for updating the question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - yes, updated the question. Although I have to say that I don't understand why it is off-topic.. it's a major aspect in software development. And to be honest, I'm feeling that there's an increasing tendency to close questions recently, the strongest - during my long years in this platform, which is troubling...

Comment: Even in a lazy language like Haskell the call to throwingFunc would be evaluated in this case (although Haskell doesn't use exceptions). You seem to want console.log to *eagerly* print it's arguments one at a time, evaluating them lazily. This isn't going to work in JS: all arguments are eagerly evaluated and no mere library is going to be able to change that, and it's unclear why you would expect one to be able to...or why you are surprised by this extremely common behavior that holds across almost every programming language...

Comment: Also probably worth noting here that the behavior of console.log is implementation-defined so even if a library could effect a change like that it would be extremely complex across different JS environments and prone to breakage on even patch updates.

Comment: @Tar asking for libraries has been off-topic as far back as I can remember (12 years on SO). You could ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/? More info https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424796/989920 https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Answer (score 2):

You can check the logger functions' arguments and when one or more of them are function and do a trial run of them before logging. Something like:

```js
const throwingFunc = () => {throw new Error(`thrown something`);};
const someMsg = () => `that worked!`;
const logger = (...args) => {
  const tryFn = fn => {
    try { return fn(); }
    catch(err) { return `*${err.message}*`; }
  }
  const evaluated = args.map(arg =>
    arg instanceof Function ? tryFn(arg) : arg);
  console.log(evaluated.join(``)); 
}

logger("Result: ", throwingFunc, `, `, someMsg);
```

Comment: The end result is still exactly the same..? The functions get called before `console.log` can print anything.

Comment: @AKX yep, think I misread the question. Edited the answer.

Comment: It's still the same result as far as I can see, aside from errors being handled differently.